# CLLocation distanceFromLocation returns wrong answer, then correct answers

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I am working on a running app, so calculating the total distance someone has traveled is important for my project. In my didUpdateLocations method, I am appending the new locations to an array and then calculating the distance between the two most recent values. The first calculation, however, is an absurdly large number. Problems persist no matter what accuracy settings I use.

Some code:

> ```
> var locationIndex = 0
>     var distanceTraveled: CLLocationDistance = 0.0
>     var allLocations = [CLLocation]()
>
>     func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
>
>         print(allLocations.count)
>
>         if locations[0].horizontalAccuracy < 15 {
>
>         self.allLocations.append(locations[0])
>
>         if allLocations.count > 1 {
>
>             var distanceIncrement = CLLocationDistance()
>
>             distanceIncrement = allLocations[allLocations.endIndex - 2].distanceFromLocation(allLocations[allLocations.endIndex - 1])
>
>             self.distanceTraveled += distanceIncrement
>             print(distanceTraveled)
>
>         }
>
>         } else {
>
>             print("Invalid")
>
>         }
>
>     }
> ```

What happens is when I print(distanceTraveled), the first value is, for example, 34.5 when simulating a run, which is absurd, since it implies that the runner moved 34.5 meters in about 1.3 seconds (the time between updates). Then, after the first print, the number increases by reasonable amounts, for example: 34.5, 39.8, 43.3, etc... Sometimes the first printed number can even be in the 500s, which is obviously not correct. Is this an issue with the simulator, or my implementation? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28953613/2303865

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience the first values you get from the location manager are bad. The very first location reading is often a cached reading from when the GPS was last "lit." You can detect and reject stale readings by checking the timestamp on the location. If it's more than a second old, discard it.

Next, the first few  location readings you get are often quite inaccurate. You want to check the horizontal accuracy reading, which is actually a "radius" value (in meters) that specifies the radius a circle in which the location might be located. Smaller values are better.

You should check the horizontal accuracy reading and discard readings where the accuracy is less than some threshold you select. I suggest 20 meters or so. Depending on the conditions you might not get ANY readings more accurate than that.

The simulator is just about worthless for testing this stuff. You need to create a test app that logs the readings you get and then get out and walk around (and/or ride as a passenger in a car/bus) with it and test it out. You might even get somebody to drive you around while you have your phone and Mac and run the app from Xcode while tethered. (I did that when I was first figuring out the subtleties of the location manager.)

Comment: Thanks. It didn't really help, but valuable advice nonetheless. I figure it's just a simulator thing. I've implemented your safe guards. For simulation purposes, i've just been throwing out the first value. Seems to work well enough.

Comment: How does it not help? Did you figure out why you were getting wrong answers followed by good ones? And are you testing on the simulator or a device?

Comment: It didn't help because no matter what I tried, I was still getting false readings on the simulator. This problem relieves itself on the actual device.

Comment: EVERY reading is false on the simulator. It doesn't have a GPS. What do yo mean, exactly?

Comment: I meant that the first reading, the incorrect "false" reading, does not occur on the actual device.