# Mapbox: User speed and distance traveled

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I am using Mapbox and Swift 3. I am trying to know what the speed of the user is as well as the distance traveled since the activity started. Any advice on how to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This isn’t a Mapbox question — you’ll want to run your own [location manager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager) or use some other iOS-provided API to track user location beyond what is shown on a map. Have a look around Stack Overflow: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28953613/2094275) may be helpful.